# Why is this still too broad?

Tags: discussion

[Learning programming language specifically designed for that company](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348420/learning-programming-language-specifically-designed-for-that-company)

So I've edited the question, and I think I'm right to point, and question is still on hold. 
What needs to be done to be "on topic"?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I see 4 reopen votes and I guess you will just have to wait some hours until you get the missing 5th. However, I can think of a dozen reasons or more why people might create a new language, so I think your question [has too many possible answers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490) to be a good fit for this site. But if the community thinks differently and vote for reopen it, I will not vote for closing it again.

Comment: so, I need to wait for one reopen vote more to start a bounty?

Comment: @JosipIvic: or you accept the rules of what the community normally thinks is too broad for this site and try to ask a more focussed question next time.

Comment: hah, it's ok. It will never get one more vote to reopen I think.